# Getting date in specific format in python

Tags: python

How can I get a date in the foll. format in python:

```
2016-04-26T19:50:48Z
```

I am doing this:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, first, you're not getting `now()` properly. That's in `datetime.datetime`, not in the top level `datetime`. Second, it doesn't seem like you've attempted to get the format string you wanted - it doesn't even have the dashes you specify.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M")
'2016 04 28 17:20'
>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
'2016-04-28T17:20:09Z'
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, it looks like you are trying to get the string representation of your date object in [ISO 8601](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) format. I don't know if you really need `Z` at the end, here is an alternative way to `.strftime()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
'2016-04-28T17:29:53'
```

I am sure you can figure sth out to append `Z` to the string.