# python correct date format from yyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyy

Tags: python

I have question, in output my date time look like this `2020-11-03` i need make something like this

```
13-Nov-20
```

my code  `_weekday = str(_row[1].strftime('%A'))`
any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? `strftime` is well documented....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting date in specific format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927538/getting-date-in-specific-format-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the form of the datetime during the datetime call with the arguments. For example:

```
"%d %b, %Y" # gives you 30 Nov, 2020
```

in your case it would be:

```
"%d-%b-%y"
```

Comment: Thank you :) you help me a lot